# Pycharm 'updating indices' for a long time scanning External Libraries directories

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I've been having some trouble with Pycharm getting stuck for a long, long time in 'updating indices'. Mouse hovering over the status bar of the updating process I can see that the directory being scanned is *C:/Anaconda/(...)*. I am in fact using the python interpreter in that directory in my project.

I am aware, as per other questions on SO and other sources, that I can avoid the 'updating indices' in my project's directories by right-clicking and selecting *'Mark directory as '* > *'Excluded'*.

However, *the Anaconda directory shows in the Project tree under 'External libraries', and I don't get that option*.

Is there a way to exclude an 'External Libraries' directory from the 'updating indices' scan?